# Way to retrieve commit details of a project and branch from gerrit rest API in python

Tags: python, git, rest, gerrit

I want to get the git log of a repository for a certain branch without doing a git clone.
I have tried the below functionalities as of now to get the details.

```
gerrit_rest(url=f"/changes/?q=project:{project}+branch:{branch}/commit")
```

but it returns an empty list.

I want output in json format which will have commit-id, author, time and date, subject.

Can you suggest what is wrong with the above command?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the contents of a "git log" using REST API in Gerrit. The endpoint you're trying to use retrieves just one commit of a specific change. The correct usage is the following:

```
/changes/CHANGE-ID/revisions/REVISION-ID/commit
```

See how to specify the CHANGE-ID [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#change-id) and the REVISION-ID [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#revision-id).

See more info about this endpoint in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-commit).